# Is it possible to query Google Cloud Storage similar to using `ls` command in terminal?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-python-api

I am using the python library for querying Google Cloud Storage, and I am organizing information in Storage using a naming hierarchy. For example:

```
my_bucket/simulations/version_1/data...
my_bucket/simulations/version_2/data...
my_bucket/simulations/version_3/data...
my_bucket/other_data/more_data...
```

My question is: is it possible to query using `list_blobs` or some other method to retrieve a list that contains just the versions from the "simulations" directory, and not all of the blobs below simulations?

For reference, this returns all blobs in a paginated fashion:

```
cursor = bucket.list_blobs(prefix='simulations')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've played around with the `prefix` and `delimiter` parameters of `list_blobs` method and this code worked:

```py
from google.cloud import storage

def ls(bucket_name, prefix, delimiter):

    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)

    cursor = bucket.list_blobs(prefix=prefix, delimiter=delimiter)
    for blob in cursor:
        pass

    for prefix in cursor.prefixes:
        print prefix

ls(your_bucket_name, 'simulations/', '/')
```

output:

```
simulations/version-1/
simulations/version-2/
simulations/version-3/
```

Note that this will only display the names of the *directories* inside the `simulations/` directory, the files will be omitted.